# indent_ctor_init_leading of uncrustify do not work

Tags: c++, uncrustify

I want the data member has four spaces after ":", so I set indent_ctor_init_leading as 4. But it always give me two spaces

expected results :

```
predictor::predictor() :
    is_human{false}{}
```

true results(only 2 spaces) :

```
predictor::predictor() :
  is_human{false}{}
```

After some experiments, I find out uncrustify indent the spaces by the configuration "indent_columns" but always ignore "indent_ctor_init_leading"(has no effect), I set "indent_class_colon" and "indent_constr_colon" as true also do not have any effect.

The configuration is based on defaults.cfg, the version of uncrustify is 0.61.3